# How to upload packages to PyPI server without setup.py?

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging

I've setup my own `PyPI` server and I periodically backup all the packages present (their `.tar.gz` to be exact) in the server. How do I upload them back to a new `PyPI` server in case of recovery or migration of hardware? (I do not want to rebuild everything and just use the existing `.tar.gz` files)

I'm using [localshop](https://github.com/mvantellingen/localshop) to run the `PyPI` server.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found out `twine` can do this quite easily.
Used this to upload my packages

`twine upload -r test dist/PACKAGENAME-VERSION.tar.gz`